# Extra pane missing from Files (Nautilus) 3.6.3 in raring tail

Tags: nautilus

I installed raring tail to have a peek at ubuntu's next version.

Then I found out that the formerly known Nautilus is now "Files". The version seem to have been kept (I have nautilus nautilus 3.4.2 in ubuntn 12.04, and Files 3.6.3 in ubuntu 13.04)

But at first sight I can see that there has been lots of changes.

What I couldn't find is the Extra Pane (f3) feature.

I was wondering if there's some way to get it back, some fork with this feature, some alternative file manager you can recommend, and if this is the file manager we will get with ubuntu 13.04

I'd also like to know if there are any more (un)features I haven't found out yet

Thanks a lot